# Spring FileSystemResource NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

I am using FileSystemResource and Spring Webflux to serve files from the hard drive.

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/news/file")
fun getImage(@RequestParam name: String): FileSystemResource {
    return FileSystemResource(propsStorage.path + "/" + name)
}
```

When the user requests an unknown file, it should be catched and an 404 error should be returned.

However I get this error:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\SomeUser\Work\posts\32.jpg
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to catch the error.
You can answer in Java if you want, I can understand both languages.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can make use of the spring [`FilesystemResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html) api exists method to avoid the `FileNotFoundException`

```
 fs =FileSystemResource(propsStorage.path + "/" + name)
if(fs.exists())
 return fs
else
return new ResponseEntity<>("File Not Found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

Also I saw that you used '/' as a separator, please note that on windows machines the file separator is ''. So for complying correctly use [`Paths.separator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator)

Answer (score 0):

You can have an `@ExceptionHandler` method for `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException` and return 404 response.

Below is in Java you can translate in kotlin.

```java
@ExceptionHandler(NoSuchFileException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleUnexpectedRollbackException(NoSuchFileException exception) {
    LOGGER.error("File not found",exception);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("File Not Found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```